# Apollo Android is generating a data class with inconsistently uppercased variables

Tags: android, apollo

I'm using Apollo Android v2.1.0, and have a `mutation` with an array of autogenerated input class:

```
mutation MyMutation($values: [MyInputClass!]) {
    exampleApi(values: $values)
}
```

This `MyInputClass` has input fields starting with both uppercase and lowercase letters:

```
{
   "kind":"INPUT_OBJECT",
   "name":"MyInputClass",
   "description":null,
   "fields":null,
   "inputFields":[
      {
         "name":"id",
         "description":null,
         "type":{
            "kind":"NON_NULL",
            "name":null,
            "ofType":{
               "kind":"SCALAR",
               "name":"String",
               "ofType":null
            }
         },
         "defaultValue":null
      },
      {
         "name":"Orientation",
         "description":null,
         "type":{
            "kind":"SCALAR",
            "name":"Int",
            "ofType":null
         },
         "defaultValue":null
      }
   ]
}
```

When Apollo Android tries to generate the data class for `MyInputClass`, it fails with:

```
Unresolved reference: Orientation
```

This is caused by the resulting `MyInputClass.kt` inconsistently using `orientation` and `Orientation`:

```
if (this@MyInputClass.Orientation.defined) {
   writer.writeInt("orientation", this@MyInputClass.orientation.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with older versions of the library, and is [fixed in v2.4.5](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/releases/tag/v2.4.5). Update your library to at least that version to resolve it.

[Here is the issue for it](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/2541), and [here is the fix](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/pull/2746).